# Errors in my project folder due to unrecognized classes. The classes are inside a referenced library inside a jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

My Eclipse project has some errors - because the classes inside the project aren't recognized.

I asked a question about this earlier, and I was asked to put the classes in a jar file. I did that, and then I added the jar to the build path.

Now, in my project folder, there is a referenced library containing my jar file full of classes. Those classes are unrecognized by my project.

Please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: can you please post exact error you are facing?

Comment: Well, I'm not very savvy with stack overflow so forgive me if all i give is this, in the problems view, it just says: *classname* cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: is your class public?

Comment: Yes..I just want to be able to use these classes without having to actually have them as files inside my project. Something like a "import java . . .*;" line of code that takes care of it

Comment: tried clean and building the project?

Comment: yup...I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: The may be frustrating to you but I have no idea what that means

Comment: What's the name of one of the classes in the jar that's not being found? What's its fully qualified path inside that jar?

Comment: Pixel.class and I'm not sure what you mean by fully qualified path? I copied the jar file, pasted it into a new folder inside my project, and then selected "add to build path" So I think the path should be okay